# Nissan Sentra 2010 MIL flashing unintelligible code

Tags: nissan, dtc, sentra

I have a Nissan Sentra 2010, and I love that it can inform the engine codes by blinking the CEL (after getting into the maintenance mode, by stepping on the gas 5 times etc etc etc). What I don't like though is that I can't really understand it! On the maintenance manual it says that between numbers it will wait 1.3 seconds, but this doesn't happen sometimes, with it cycling between long blinks and fast blinks without waiting! I just couldn't really get any real code from this 3:00 footage:

[Nissan Sentra 2010 CEL light blinking](https://youtu.be/n1trrZoCxxY)

Here are the instructions on how to read it from the manual:

[image: Procedure to read engine codes]

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Your video is set up as "private" requiring login by a particular user.

Comment: Argh... thanks! Just changed it!

Comment: Vehicles sold in the USA market are required to have OBDII on board self diagnostic systems since 1996. Virtually all OBDII ports are located near the steering column. Here's a video to help; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMKbCX5GD4w  The OBDII port has a D shape, 16 pins for connection to a scantool whether purchased for personal use or visiting auto stores like Autozone for free readings.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the OBDII port (but thanks!). I tried 2 cheap scantools, all which couldn't connect to my car, and no such free reading service here in Brazil. What I wanted to see was if someone had seem such an issue with the blinking CEL light, it would be super useful if I could understand it. Maybe there's a problem with the diagnostic system, who knows. The car works almost flawlessly, other than what seems like a ocasional "spark skip", making the engine a bit rough for a second & then turning on the CEL light. The CEL light goes away again after some days. I'll try to change a coil